# Django ModelForm display model field of foreign key instead object id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to show a model field in a select field in my template. I am using a foreign key which is selected in the select field. The problem is that only the object id is shown.

How can I make it show a model field of my foreign key ('crt_id' from Certificate model for example) and not an object and the id? (see picture)

[image]

Thank you in advance

my code:

Certificate model

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    crt_id = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    crt_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    crt_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Device model

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    device_group = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    device_certificate = models.ForeignKey(Certificate, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    device_group = forms.CharField(required=False)
    device_name = forms.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Device
        fields = [
            'device_name',
            'device_group',
            'device_certificate'
        ]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define what your model will return.

Just add at the end of Device model definition something like:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.device_name
```

Or whatever you wish to be returned or in your case it would be:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.device_certificate
```

and do the same in Certificate model to indicate what it should return.

One of the popular things to do is to combine multiple fields like this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.device_name + ' (' + self.device_certificate + ')'
```

or any other combination you would require.

Comment: BTW, you can construct whatever you want to be returned by combining fields, doing calculations or anything else you wish to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Just add str function in your foreign reference model Product.

```
class Certificate(models.Model):
    crt_id = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    crt_expire = models.DateTimeField()
    crt_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id)
```